# typescript using properties class for multiple calles

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, class, ecmascript-6

Ive create a class which needs to call to other class and get data

E.g

```
import { SC } from "./svc/service";





export default class myClass{

//Here define the variable 
sc: SC;

async initializing() {

// Here I’ve created the instance
this.sc = new SC();

this.sc.getServices()

}


Async   testValue{

//Now when I call to the function from here in debug I see that this inside `SERVICE_INSTANCE` is empty , why ????
this.sc.getServices()

} 


}



export default class SC{


SERVICE_INSTANCE: string[] = [];


async getServices(

//If the function already called I’m returning the value

If(this.SERVICE_INSTANCE){
return this.SERVICE_INSTANCE;
}

….
//here  when the function called first I got data and assign the service instance to avoid hits
this.SERVICE_INSTANCE = GetData();


}

}
```

Why when I call to the function `getService` in the second time I got `If(this.SERVICE_INSTANCE){` which is undefined why?

I can store the property in global level but I want to avoid it, **Im not creating another instance** , just one instance inside `initilizing` and use it on `testValue` function...

**The problem that in the second call `this` is undefined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your SERVICE_INSTANCE is of type string[], your check `if(this.SERVICE_INSTANCE)` will always be true which is why it is returning empty array always.

You need to check `if(this.SERVICE_INSTANCE.length)`

Comment: Thanks it's a bit more complicated then this...:) , the `this` is undefined in the second call